# ChartJS - Custom tooltip with icon

Tags: angular, chart.js

Is there an option to create custom tooltips with ChartJS in Angular which displays custom icon on the left side and some data parameters on the right side (50% 50% witdh). I've seen some ideas but none with images included. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chart.js provides for "[External (Custom) Tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips)" that can be built using whatever HTML you choose:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
    enabled: false,
    custom: function(tooltipModel) {
      // your custom tooltip code ...
```

Multiple examples are provided on the [Chart.js samples page](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/):

- [HTML tooltips (line)](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-line.html)
- [HTML tooltips (pie)](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-pie.html)
- [HTML tooltips (points)](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/custom-points.html)

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986669/chartjs-custom-tooltip-with-icon#comment106090163_59987039), here's a quick example of loading an image in a tooltip using the code in the documentation:

```js
const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Series 1",
      data: [1, 4, 2]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      custom: function(tooltipModel) {
        // Hide if no tooltip
        if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
          tooltip.style.opacity = 0;
          return;
        }

        // show the tooltip.
        tooltip.style.opacity = 1;

        // create the img element and append it to the tooltip element.
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6fcc51ca5e7029116a383e7aeb0bbaa0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
        tooltip.innerHTML = "";
        tooltip.appendChild(img);

        // move the tooltip to the 'correct' position.
        const position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        tooltip.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
        tooltip.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: I've already seen this, but I just can't find an example working with images. Thanks for answer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, it is something to get you started.

You can create a custom tooltip using the renderer. You can also use the document like they did at the bottom here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html but it may not work with server side generated applications.

The `thisAsThat` is a good utility function => it allows you to refer to the Chart.js object as `that` and allows you to refer to the class as `this`.

At the bottom of this page of the link I provided, it shows how to make a custom tooltip. Take your time in going through it. Basically everywhere they use the `document`, you can use the `renderer`. To position and style the tooltip it is up to you and you may have to do calculations.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

private thisAsThat(callBack: Function) {
  const self = this;
  return function () {
      return callBack.apply(self, [this].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  }; 
}

options: {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false,
    custom: this.thisAsThat((that, tooltipModel: any) => {
      // maybe you need chartPosition
      const chartPosition = that._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const tooltipEl = this.renderer.createElement('div');
      const image = this.renderer.createElement('img');
      // Pretty sure it is setProperty, can also give setAttribute a try as well
      this.renderer.setProperty(image, 'src', 'src of image here');
      this.renderer.setProperty(image, 'alt', 'Your alt');
      this.renderer.appendChild(tooltipEl, image);
      // Can also add a class as well.
      this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipEl, 'background', 'black');
      // this should add your tooltip at the end of the DOM right before the body tag
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, tooltipEl);
   })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really the case I was looking for! :) Very much appreciated!

Comment: This is great addition, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In V3 the tooltip config has been moved to the `options.plugins.tooltip` namespace, also the `custom` option has been renamed to `external`. Since it renders just html you can pass anything to it you want like so:

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
const getOrCreateTooltip = (chart) => {
  let tooltipEl = chart.canvas.parentNode.querySelector('div');

  if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipEl.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)';
    tooltipEl.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    tooltipEl.style.color = 'white';
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
    tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
    tooltipEl.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, 0)';
    tooltipEl.style.transition = 'all .1s ease';

    const table = document.createElement('table');
    table.style.margin = '0px';

    tooltipEl.appendChild(table);
    chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
  }

  return tooltipEl;
};

const externalTooltipHandler = (context) => {
  // Tooltip Element
  const {
    chart,
    tooltip
  } = context;
  const tooltipEl = getOrCreateTooltip(chart);

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    const titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    const bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(b => b.lines);

    const tableHead = document.createElement('thead');

    titleLines.forEach(title => {
      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const th = document.createElement('th');
      th.style.borderWidth = 0;
      const text = document.createTextNode(title);
      th.appendChild(text);

            // THIS BLOCK ADDED
      const imageTh = document.createElement('th');
      th.style.borderWidth = 0;
      const image = document.createElement('img');
      image.style = 'width:20px'
      image.src = context.tooltip.dataPoints[0].dataset.url;
      imageTh.appendChild(image);

      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.appendChild(imageTh);
      tableHead.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    bodyLines.forEach((body, i) => {
      const colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];

      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.style.background = colors.backgroundColor;
      span.style.borderColor = colors.borderColor;
      span.style.borderWidth = '2px';
      span.style.marginRight = '10px';
      span.style.height = '10px';
      span.style.width = '10px';
      span.style.display = 'inline-block';

      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
      tr.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.style.borderWidth = 0;

      const text = document.createTextNode(body);

      td.appendChild(span);
      td.appendChild(text);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });

    const tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');

    // Remove old children
    if(tableRoot && tableRoot.firstChild) {
    while (tableRoot.firstChild) {
      tableRoot.firstChild.remove();
    }
    }
    

    // Add new children
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableHead);
    tableRoot.appendChild(tableBody);
  }

  const {
    offsetLeft: positionX,
    offsetTop: positionY
  } = chart.canvas;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.font = tooltip.options.bodyFont.string;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.options.padding + 'px ' + tooltip.options.padding + 'px';
};

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        url: 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/512px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        position: 'nearest',
        external: externalTooltipHandler
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Fiddle link since stack sandbox didnt like the table: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/xhrs2wvc/19/